# Angular 8: singleton service creating new instances each time it is required on a new file

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-services, behaviorsubject

I have a fully working platform that uses Rxjs Behavior Subjects (Observables) in services to keep the state of the entire application. It was working pretty fine until I needed to include WebSockets to update information across many users in the same account.
As the information updated gets to the users, I call the behavior subject to check if the active supplier (the one the user is currently seeing) should be updated, but the Observable always return "null", as it is a new instance of that Observable (and not the same that is showing in the user's screen).

To test it, I logged the same observable in two different files:

**//Supplier.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Supplier } from '../../models/supplier.model';
import { UserService } from './User.service';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class SupplierService {
  activeSupplier = new BehaviorSubject<Supplier>(null);

  constructor (
    private http: HttpClient,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}

{...}

getOneSupplier(supplierId: string) {
  this.http.get<Supplier>(`${BASEURL}supplier/${supplierId}`)
    .subscribe(supplier => {
        this.activeSupplier.next(supplier);
        this.activeSupplier.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(activeSupplier => {
        console.log('updater:', activeSupplier); // <----------------- here
    });
  });
}

updateSupplierList(changedSupplier) {
    this.activeSupplier.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(activeSupplier => {
      console.log('Socket changing active supplier:', activeSupplier);
        if (activeSupplier._id === changedSupplier._id) {
          this.getOneSupplier(activeSupplier._id);
      }
    });
  }

{...}

}
```

**//Socket.service.js**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import io from './SocketCopier.js';
import { UserService } from './User.service.js';
import { SupplierService } from './Supplier.service.js';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SocketService {
socket;
subs = {};

constructor(
private userService: UserService,
private supplierService: SupplierService
) {
this.supplierService.activeSupplier.subscribe(activeSupplier => {
  console.log('socket:', activeSupplier); // <----------------- and here
});
}

loadSocket(user) {
io.then((result) => {
  if (this.socket) {
    this.socket.close();
  }

  this.socket = result('http://localhost:3000');
  this.socket.on('connect', () => {
    this.socket.emit('login', { account: user.account._id })
  });

  this.socket.on('logged', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg.text);
  });

  this.socket.on('supplierChange', (msg) => {
    this.supplierService.updateSupplierList(msg.data);
  });
});
}

}
```

**//supplier-info.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SupplierService } from 'src/app/shared/services/Supplier.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Supplier } from 'src/app/models/supplier.model';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-supplier-info',
  templateUrl: './supplier-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./supplier-info.component.css'],
})
export class SupplierInfoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  supplier: Supplier;
  subs = {};
  activeRoute: string = 'projetos';

  constructor(
    private supplierService: SupplierService, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.supplierService.getOneSupplier(this.route.snapshot.params.supplierId);
  }

  {...}

}
```

The code calls first the Socket.service.ts, which calls Supplier.service.ts, which creates the behavior subject "activeSupplier" with "null" as the initial value.

Then Socket.service.ts, in its constructor, subscribes to "activeSupplier" observable and returns "null" as expected.

Then the supplier-info.component.ts is generated and in ngOnInit it requires for the supplier info, calling "this.supplierService.getOneSupplier()". This updates the "activeSupplier" BehaviorSubject, which logs the supplier.

This is the result I get from these logs:

```
socket: null
updater: {socialMediaUrls: {…}, photoUrl: "", emails: Array(0), skills: Array(0), tags: Array(4), …}
```

Socket's observable is never updated again, as it is a new instance of "supplierService" and it's not sharing the same "activeSupplier" with supplier-info.component.ts. It should be updated, right? As it is subscribed to the same Observable (at least theoretically).

What I'm not seeing here?
Thanks in advance for all your help!

edit:
It is worth saying that any new subscription to "activeSupplier" Observable subscription returns "null" as it's the first value (even after the second console.log with a supplier).

Comment: I see, you have injected the service in the root, By any chance is it possible, that you would have provided the service in a feature module? Because that might lead to create the separate instance of that service for the components under that module.

Comment: As I'm pretty new to Angular, I have just one module (app.module.ts) and It has no services provided there - just checked by the way. Not even a reference for them in the file. All services are provided with "@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})".

Anywhere else I should look for? Maybe I just don't know where this "provided the service in a feature module" could be in.

Comment: Refer this documentation https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services . Your service instance creation and singleton service scope are based on the way you provide service.

Comment: @PushpikaWan I've checked this documentation and that's what I'm following all over my code. All my services are provided on their own file with "@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})" and they're not provided anywhere else. I've just checked with Visual Studio Code search in the whole project folder and there's nothing being provided outside of it's own file (for 'root') :(

Comment: What is the `updateSupplierList` doing? It seems that `updateSupplierList` is the method called when the socket receives a message.

Comment: @Picci It should update the current supplier on the screen, but the activeSupplier Observable returns 'null' even when there is a supplier active on the screen:

`updateSupplierList(changedSupplier) {
    this.activeSupplier.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(activeSupplier => {
      console.log('Socket changing active supplier:', activeSupplier);
       if (activeSupplier._id === changedSupplier._id) {
         this.getOneSupplier(activeSupplier._id);
      }
    });
  }`

Comment: So maybe it is in `updateSupplierList` method that you should `next` the `Subject`, if I have understood the problem

Comment: As I see now, in `updateSupplierList` you do not `next` the Subject, rather you subscribe to the same Subject you initially create, And this same Subject is not going to give you anything but `null`, again, unless I miss something in the problem.

Comment: I was trying to edit the code to show it better up there, but I'm failling to get it properly indented.
This part of the code gets the changes, checks whether an update is needed or not and then calls the "getOneSupplier" function that should do the job of nexting the Subject.

But I never get there, because it would say that activeSupplier is always 'null'. Apparently Socket.service.ts is creating a new instance of supplierService.service.ts, so the nexts that happened before never gets to it.

Comment: The activeSupplier Subject is not null in any other part of the code. Just when I call this "updateSupplierList" from Socket.service.ts.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment and the code in it, I think you can try something like this.

First you save somewhere the value of the **active supplier** you receive from the http service, probably at start. Something like this

```
export class SupplierService {
  activeSupplier = new BehaviorSubject<Supplier>(null);
  activeSupplierValue: Supplier;

  constructor (
    private http: HttpClient,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {}
...

getOneSupplier(supplierId: string) {
  this.http.get<Supplier>(`${BASEURL}supplier/${supplierId}`)
    .subscribe(supplier => {
        this.activeSupplierValue = supplier;  // save the data of the active supplier
        ......
    });
  });
}
...

}
```

Then you compare the **active supplier** with whatever you receive from the socket and, if there is a match, you fire the `getOneSupplier` all again.

```
updateSupplierList(changedSupplier) {
   if (activeSupplier._id === changedSupplier._id) {
      this.getOneSupplier(activeSupplier._id);
   }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't work either :(... To debug it, I did this "this.activeSupplierValue = supplier;" and logged just after it "console.log(this.activeSupplierValue + ' - ' + new Date(Date.now()))". Then I did the same logging inside "updateSupplierList". The results: (1) [object Object] - Sun Mar 22 2020 23:55:58 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) | (2) undefined - Sun Mar 22 2020 23:56:06 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time).

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
After many (MANY) debugging logs I found out I was really creating another instance of the service. To find this out I logged the Supplier.service.ts constructor. Then I saw that both logs were happening in different lines. Opening those files (chrome inspect > source) I saw they were different (?), so I tried to "re-write" the imports in Sockets.service.ts and it worked!

That's because I was importing it wrongly (with a '.js' on the end).

From this:

```
import { UserService } from './User.service.js';
import { SupplierService } from './Supplier.service.js';
```

To this:

```
import { UserService } from './User.service';
import { SupplierService } from './Supplier.service';
```

And now everything works fine!